# search for files in S3, when given a path

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given a path to S3 bucket, I need to find another file in the same path and work on it as well.

- I am using Django in Python.
- I have a model named "HouseList" and a model named "CustomerFile"
- I am using a function that returns a list of HouseList objects that I need to modify.

For each object there, I have a file path, and in that path, I can find the corresponding customer file, as you can see in these prints from the terminal:

```
In [7]: HouseList.objects.get(id=11508).file_path
Out[7]: u'85/1545927/omc_emea_hl_small.csv'

In [8]: CustomerFile.objects.get(id=5031).file_path
Out[8]: u'85/1545927/omc_emea_pos_small.csv'
```

Is there a way, given a prefix of the path, to get a list of all the files that are located there?

Comment: So, you simply want a list of all objects in that bucket with a prefix of `85/1545927/`?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) function can return a list of objects for a given prefix:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='string',
    Delimiter='string',
    EncodingType='url',
    MaxKeys=123,
    Prefix='string',
    ContinuationToken='string',
    FetchOwner=True|False,
    StartAfter='string',
    RequestPayer='requester'
)
```

So, you'd use something like:

```
path = HouseList.objects.get(id=11508).file_path

response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=your_bucket,
    Prefix=path[:path.rfind('/')+1],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use s3 boto module in Python to list files with given prefix as standing there: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list

> prefix (string) – allows you to limit the listing to a particular prefix. For example, if you call the method with prefix=’/foo/’ then the iterator will only cycle through the keys that begin with the string ‘/foo/’.